# Entity Not Found In DB but present in Persistence Context

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I'm creating a resource subscription using transaction 1, before this transaction 1 returns , it adds the request , response and jpa query fetched just created subscription resource into a queue which is taken care by by executor service threads.

This executorService starts separate transaction 2, a uses to jpa query to read a specific attribute of subscription resource ,but it gets null value , but the previous transaction 1 found it(coz may be it itself created it). Transaction 2 need to read the current value but not founding it.

I'm using Ecliplink 2.6, JDK 1.8 and Wildfly 10.Final.

I have looked into whether eclipselink have persisted it to DB or kept in persistenceContext coz, transaction is still not complete and new transaction trying to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal transaction behavior.

As long as T1 is not commited T2 cannot see the data from T1.

Comment: Thanks Simon for prompt reply. I was wondering if not from database, but I could read from persistenceContext using JPA query. Would that be possible ?

Comment: No the Persistence Context is bound to the transaction.